# Is it possible to refresh forms with new fields added to a list type?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, column, form

Is it possible to automatically generate any columns that are added to a list on its corresponding forms or do I need to recreate the form altogether in order for the additional columns to appear?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using custom New/Display/Edit forms, then adding the new column to List will automatically reflect into these forms. The only thing you need to consider is you are adding a new column to right content type. And you open any of the form using that content type, then you can see your column.

In case of InfoPath forms, you need to edit the form using Info, refresh the columns section and drag drop the new column to form area to get it.

Comment: Do they have to be named as such?  Let's say instead of using `NewForm.aspx`, I set the default new form to be `CustomForm.aspx`.  Will adding a column be reflected on `CustomForm.aspx`?

Comment: No, its not required. But if you are using customization then you need to take care, otherwise it comes OOTB. You are using InfoPath forms or something else?

Comment: I am using SharePoint Designer...no InfoPath :)